# Override id for class positioning

Tags: javascript, css, class, overriding

I have an id for an element, with css as so:

```css
 #red {
     background-color: #2ac0a3;
     border-top-left-radius: 5px;
     border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
     position: relative;
     bottom: 220px;
     left: 365px;
 }
```

I want to add a class to #red div to override the position, however it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas how?

JS:

```
$('#red').addClass('ya');
```

CSS

```
.ya{
position: relative;
left: 900px;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Google "css precedence".

Answer (score 2):

IDs have higher precedence than classes. To override the ID style, you need a more specific selector:

```css
.ya, #red.ya {
    position: relative;
    left: 900px;
}
```

Comment: You can also use the `!important` flag for any CSS rule.

Answer (score 0):

The values in the "id" (#red) are more specific then a class (E.G. ".ya"). Thus, the CSS rules set in the "id" take precedence (I.E. are the rules that are applied).

If you inline the attributes that will be even more specific and thus take precedence over the "id" rules. Inline meaning  add the values as a "style" attribute.

```
 <sometag style="position: relative;left: 900px;" </sometag>
```

With JQuery something like

```
$('#red').attrib('style','position: relative;left: 900px;');
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Use `.css()` rather than `.attrib`.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget about the !important flag that you can set with any CSS.

For instance:

```
#red {
  background-color: #2ac0a3;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 220px;
  left: 365px;
}
```

...can be overwritten by:

```
.ya {
  position: relative !important;
  left: 900px !important;
}
```

This has several advantages in keeping your CSS clean and tidy and more easy to manage when you need to get in and change it or add to it down the road.

Additionally, here's a fiddle for demonstration of the concept:
http://jsfiddle.net/WDgNF/